# CSS Affect only parent list in the nested list

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, parent

I have a nested list, as shown below. I'm struggling to find a specific CSS selector that I can use in `querySelectorAll()` JavaScript function, which will only affect all `<li>` tags that do NOT contain `<ul>` tag. So in this case it should be just the lines

```
    <li>foot</li>
    <li>leg</li>
    <li>tiger</li>
    <li>elephant</li>
    <li>food</li>
```

I tried `querySelectorAll("ol > li")` and some others ways with the `:not()` selector, but to no success.

`querySelectorAll("ol > li ul")` is the opposite of what I want, because when I use
`console.log(document.getElementById("translation").querySelectorAll("ol > li ul").length)` it returns `3`.

I need code of the following type `console.log(document.getElementById("translation").querySelectorAll(`blank`).length)` which will return `5`. I don't know if that's possible, and I can't find it anywhere online.

Another way of looking at it is to let this code of CSS only color items which do not contain other nested lists (so that only points 2-6 will have colored background):

```
#translation ol > li ul{
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

The entire list:

```
<div id="translation">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>parting</li>
        <li>parting</li>
        <li>parting</li>
        <li>separation</li>
        <li>separation</li>
        <li>separation</li>
        <li>farewell</li>
        <li>(lateral) branch</li>
        <li>fork</li>
        <li>offshoot</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>foot</li>
    <li>leg</li>
    <li>tiger</li>
    <li>elephant</li>
    <li>food</li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>branch</li>
        <li>parting</li>
        <li>disaffiliation</li>
        <li>disaffiliation</li>
        <li>separation</li>
        <li>(lateral) branch</li>
        <li>farewell</li>
        <li>branch</li>
        <li>division</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>dissociation</li>
        <li>disaffiliation</li>
        <li>dissociation</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check each li is childNodes has ul. For example like this:

```
const test = [...document.querySelectorAll("ol > li")].filter(
  li => ![...li.childNodes].find(child => child.localName === "ul")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to use jQuery then make the :not selector to catch elements that have ul as childs.
something like this:

```
$("translation").find("ol > li:not(:has(>ul))")
```

Notice this solution will work for jQuery selectors but not for the Vanilla JS (Vanilla JS doesn't support `:has` as a seclctor).

With Vanilla JS you might want to do something like this:

```
const elems = document.getElementById("translation").querySelectorAll('ol > li');
let items = Array.from(elems); // convert to Array type

items.filter(item => { // filter the array
  item.querySelectorAll('ul').length == 0
})
```